# Can a WiFi module detect location?

Tags: google-maps, arduino

I have a CC3000 WiFi Shield connected to my Arduino and it is connected to a router. Is it possible for me to detect my location? (location via google maps)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of arduino gps shield and Google Maps you will have latitude and longitude of arduino gps shield, but to detect router's latitude I have no idea whether it supports GIS or not. but using its antenna's radius as a center point you can develop a logic to point it out. You can also consider signal strength as a parameter because as you move away from antenna it will loose its strength and become weak. Sorry if this doesn't work.

I would like to point your attention to the following project and software:

http://www.storm.net.nz/projects/5

The ghetto way of doing the same, is to use a directional antenna with netstumbler, or something that shows signal strength. Find the maximum strength with the directional antenna, mark the angle, and try again from another point or two. Triangulate, and you'll know the location of the access point.

If you want avoid this mathematical stuff you can find out the ip address of router somehow using some command and use a web service of 3rd party that provides location via the ip address of router.